# Paypal smart buttons credit card fill or hide phone number

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

I'm allowing credit card payment with paypal smart buttons. This is how my createOrder looks like:

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    paypalActions = actions;
    return fetch('/basket/get/lineitems', {
            method: 'get'
        }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(orderData) {
            orderDataArray = [orderData]
            return actions.order.create({
                payer: {
                    name: {
                    given_name: "PayPal",
                    surname: "Customer"
                    },
                    address: {
                    address_line_1: '123 ABC Street',
                    address_line_2: 'Apt 2',
                    admin_area_2: 'San Jose',
                    admin_area_1: 'CA',
                    postal_code: '95121',
                    country_code: 'US'
                    },
                    email_address: "customer@domain.com",
                    phone: {
                    phone_type: "MOBILE",
                    phone_number: {
                        national_number: "12345678"
                    }
                    }
                },
                purchase_units: orderDataArray,
                shipping_type: 'PICKUP',
                application_context: { shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING' }
            })
        });

},
```

(The fetch requests gets my card items.)

Following the docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/standard-card-fields/#optimize-the-card-fields it's working nicely to pass the billing address which I already have. Only the phone Number does not get filled.

[image]

What is needed to fill the phone field with above example? Or even better is it possible to set it to not required?

Comment: The example you have doesn't have enough digits for the phone number.  so for a US Number you need +1 ### ### #### (10 digits)

Comment: Thanks @Shenanigator but even with `national_number: "1234567890"` it does not get filled out. Can you say if it's possible to completely remove or ignore the phone field?

Comment: according to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-phone no; it is required with no way around that.

Comment: "1234567890" is still not right; try national_number: "12535551212"

Comment: Thanks @Shenanigator I can confirm that it's the length. If I pass a german address and a german mobile number it get's filled out! Grazie! mille!

Answer (score 1):

The number length for National Numbers is a validation for the API; using the US example you needed the correct length of the phone number.  For US Numbers it expects 1 ### ### ####